# MySQL: Return maximum value for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
select username as User, floor((count(Goals)/2)-(if(sum(Loss)>0,1,0))) as Round, sum(Win) as Wins, sum(Goals) as Goals, sum(Loss) as Losses, campaign, Season, ((floor((count(Goals)/2)-(if(sum(Loss)>0,1,0)))*100000)+(sum(Win)*100)+sum(Goals)) as Score from
            (select u.username as username, s.campaignno as campaign, if(f.hometeamscore>f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Win, if(f.hometeamscore<f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Loss, f.hometeamscore as Goals, ss.seasonid as Season from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u, straightred_season ss where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.hometeamid and s.user_id = u.id union all
             select u.username as username, s.campaignno as campaign, if(f.awayteamscore>f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Win, if(f.awayteamscore<f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Loss, f.awayteamscore as Goals, ss.seasonid as Season from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u, straightred_season ss where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.awayteamid and s.user_id = u.id) t
            group by username, campaign, Season
            having Season = 1025
            order by Round DESC, Wins DESC, Goals DESC;
```

Which returns the following results:

```
 +----------------------+-------+------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
| User                 | Round | Wins | Goals | Losses | campaign  | Season | Score  |
+----------------------+-------+------+-------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
| shanu                |     9 |   12 |    36 |      1 | 354102525 |   1025 | 901236 |
| snookro              |     7 |   10 |    28 |      2 | 358102528 |   1025 | 701028 |
| tingeypa             |     6 |    9 |    19 |      2 |  35910257 |   1025 | 600919 |
| shaun                |     5 |    9 |    30 |      1 | 372102520 |   1025 | 500930 |
| shanu                |     5 |    9 |    25 |      2 |  35410256 |   1025 | 500925 |
| snookro              |     4 |    9 |    26 |      1 | 358102518 |   1025 | 400926 |
| chrakers             |     4 |    8 |    26 |      2 | 378102531 |   1025 | 400826 |
| freebet              |     4 |    8 |    24 |      1 | 375102524 |   1025 | 400824 |
```

The resulting table is correct but I only want the maximum "Score" for each "User".  As you can see both "shanu" and "snookro" have two entries in the table.

I have tried to wrap the score with the max function but MySQL tells me "Invalid use of group function".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that is because they have different `campaign` id number

Comment: Oh yes, that won't help.  Can I keep the campaign number (but not group them) and then use the max on the score?

Comment: That is not possible as far as I know

Comment: technically no.. and it is meaningless :)

Comment: This is a "groupwise max" problem: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: Why is it meaningless?

Comment: If I take out campaign can I then easily just return one?

Comment: what is the purpose of having the same max across two different group? max is using for getting the highest within the same group, and I deleted my answer for not noticing the aggregate function you are using, try to wrap all columns with aggregate function, otherwise, columns specified in `group by` cannot be selected

Comment: I was going to use it at a later date in a python program BUT it is NOT essential.  So, assuming i lose campaign is it then possible?

Comment: Yes, either to take out `campaign`, or doing further update I guess

Comment: OK, will I do need the campaign as that is what works out how goals and how many wins a user have.  Could you elaborate on the further update part?

Comment: Try the Max(score) function with group by user 'select user,max(score) from ( your query) t1 group by user'

Comment: Jaydee, appreciate your response but I just can't quite work out where that should go.  Am I putting this as another level of the select? UPDATE:  Just tried it and that worked.  Would you like to put that as the official answer?  Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Jaydee, can you put an answer so I may accept it?